# Canvas transparency on IE

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transparency, kineticjs

When I draw a rectangle or other shape on canvas (using kineticJS, creating a `new Kinetic.Path`), and set `fill: none` as in the following:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Path({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            data: 'm 2.0012417,2.0057235 125.7664883,0 0,105.8016465 -125.7664883,0 z',
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: 'black',
            scale: 1
});
```

...then in Chrome and Firefox the shape is transparent as it should be. However in IE9 the shape is black.

See for example
http://jsfiddle.net/T8m64/107/
Look at the black rectangle at the top left of that example -- it's transparent with black border in Chrome/Firefox, and black-filled-black-bordered in IE.

Anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
fill: 'none',
```

Use this:

```
fill: null,
```